# PHP DateDiff Bug?

Tags: php, datediff

I have the following problem
First here is my code:

```
$day_difference = 1;
while (strtotime('-' . $day_difference . ' day', time()) >= strtotime('2011-12-12 00:08:00')) {
    #echo $day_difference;
    $day_difference++;
}
$datediff = $day_difference;
```

**This code should output 1 day not 2 days**

**What is wrong ?**

Comment: It doesn't? http://codepad.org/zTJEgspS

Comment: okay it seems that is relevant to timezone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running PHP 5.3, you should use the native `DateTime` API.

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime('2011...');
$interval = $date->diff(new DateTime);
var_dump($interval);
?>
```

Comment: +1 `DateTime()` overcomes a lot of headaches involved when dealing with time, including timezones (among other things).